# AWS Role with a PolicyDocument assuming itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to understand code written by coworker that has left.
Can anyone tell me why we have a Policy that assume the role it's attached too, what is it suppose to do?

```json
{
  "Role1": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "ManagedPolicyArns": [],
      "Policies": []
    },
    
    "AssumeRolePermissions": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "DependsOn": "Role1",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Resource": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "Role1", "Arn" ] }
            }
          ]
        },
        "PolicyName": "Assume_Role",
        "Roles": [{ "Ref": "Role1" }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know a trust policy is useful in the case I want Role2 to assume Role1's permissions.
From the new update (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/announcing-an-update-to-iam-role-trust-policy-behavior/) if seems in that case I need both of them in the trust policy but what if I don't do that, is there a use case for assuming its own role?

Thanks

```json
  "Role1": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "AWS": { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "Role1", "Arn" ] }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "ManagedPolicyArns": [],
      "Policies": []
    }
```

PS: It was used for a Scope Down policy in my case and following the new update I have made another role B that will assume the Role A instead of using Role A with a Scope Down policy attached to it.

Comment: It certainly seems strange! I can't think of a benefit of an IAM Role calling `AssumeRole()` on itself, unless the intention is to extend the validity period of the returned credentials.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I guess it must have been a mistake or other roles attached to that policy must have been removed

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JohnRotenstein and AWS support:

A role assuming itself is a rare use case that while valid isn't an AWS best practice, with AWS recommending using multiple roles instead.
Some of these use cases involve self-assuming in conjunction with a 'scoped-down' policy to obtain a different privilege level, or using a single role and policy throughout the development => build => test => production environment, or can be used to rotate the access/secret keys used by the role since when you role chain the session only last one hour.

All that being said in the majority of cases a self assuming role is a step that depends on use case.

Comment: it's a fairly common pattern now: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/announcing-an-update-to-iam-role-trust-policy-behavior/